# How to uninstall/turn off Microsoft Groove 2007

Tags: uninstall, microsoft-office-2007

I'm a college student and purchased the Microsoft Office Ultimate 2007 CD for $60.

All I really wanted was Word/Powerpoint/Excel/Outlook, but it installs about a half dozen other office products in addition.

Being the curious person that I am, I went through all of these programs to find out what they did.

Groove is apparently some kind of file syncing thing, but now that I've opened it, I can't seem to get it to turn off (i.e. it will always appear in the system tray AND whenever I right click on the desktop a link for groove comes up).

The problem is you can't just uninstall groove, you can only uninstall the entire suite - something I obviously don't want to do. Anybody have an idea?

If it matters, I run windows 7.

Comment: I faced this problem too on another computer.  Do let us know which method from the 2 answers fixed your problem.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't seem to get it to turn off -
>   i.e. it will always appear in the
>   system tray

Download and run **[Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)** (Sysinternals' excellent startup manager) and clear the checkbox to disable **GrooveMonitor**.

[image]

> AND whenever I right click on the
>   desktop a link for groove comes up.

Download and run NirSoft's **[ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)**, locate and **highlight** the Groove shell extension and press **F7** (or right click on it and select **Disable Selected Items**).

[image]

Restart your computer ... done and dusted!

*Autoruns and ShellExView are freeware and 'portable' (no installation required).*

Answer (score 1):

See this Microsoft article: [How to uninstall Groove](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907504).

The section you're interested in is probably "How to uninstall Groove 2007 and remove all associated data".